# A function f is even. Ithere are 4 values $x_1 ,x_2 , x_3, x_4$ satisfying $f(\frac{x+1}{3-x}) = f(x)$, then the value of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A function f is even. It is known that there are four values $x_1 ,x_2 , x_3, x_4$ satisfying $f(\frac{x+1}{3-x}) = f(x)$, then the value of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$ is
A)0
B)2
C)4
D)6

**My attempt:**  I just tried doing $\frac{x+1}{3-x} = \pm \ x$ and I got $ x = 1,\, 2 + \sqrt{5}\,  2 - \sqrt{5}$.

That leaves one more value of x right so does it mean the f is a many-one function if it is then I should get 4 more solutions, what am I missing and what's the final answer?

Comment: You're on the right track. What you have shown is that If $f$ is one-to-one on $[0, \infty)$, then there are only 3 possible solutions. Since we're given that there are 4 such values, we can conclude that $f$ is not one-to-one. $\quad $ So how can we add just a 4th solution, without adding a 5th solution? If $f(3) = f(2)$, how many more solutions could there be?

Comment: There would be 4 in total, Right, I thought (x+1)/(3-x) [g(x)] was even hence what i thought was if f(g(x)) = f(x) , for x not equal to g(x) then f(g(x)) = f(x) = f(-x) = f(g(-x)), but since it isn't how can we arbitrarily define the 4th solution ?

Comment: Why would there be exactly 4 in total? What is the 4th root? How do you know there there are no other roots? EG $f(3) = f(2) = f(-3) = f(-2)$, so did you hunt everything properly? (Note: I specially selected $f(3) = f(2)$.)

Comment: doesnt matter if f(3) = f(2) = f(-3) = f(-2) , point is -2 doesnt satisfy f(g(-2)) = f(-2) since g(-2) is not -3

Comment: If roots do not have to be unique, you could say that $x=1$ is a double root. Then, $f$ may be 1-1.

Comment: @AadiSinha: What do you mean by 'there are four values'? Exactly four values?

Comment: exactly four @Marian G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$g(x):=f\left(\frac{x+1}{3-x}\right).\tag{1}$$

We are looking for the roots of :

$$h(x):=g(x)-f(x)=0\tag{2}$$

If $f$ is differentiable, the fact that

$$g'(x)=f'\left(\frac{x+1}{3-x}\right)\frac{4}{(3-x)^2}$$

implies $g'(1)=f'(1).1.$

As $g(1)=f(1)$, we can conclude that point $1$ is a double root of equation (2). Otherwise said, root $1$ has to be counted twice. Therefore the result is :

$$(2-\sqrt{5})+(2+\sqrt{5})+1+1=6$$

**(Answer D)**.

Consider the case of parametric function :

$$f_a(x):=0.25x^2+a\frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}$$

first in the case $-0.2<a<4$. With the interpretation where double root $1$ is considered only once, one can be convinced with the interactive animation [here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/u9c2f7as) that one jumps from  3 roots (in fact 4) materialized by little disks, to 5 (in fact 6, when root $1$ is counted twice) when $a$ is outside interval $[-0.2,4]$ .

[image]

Fig. 1: *In red : the "permanent points" with abscissas $2 \pm \sqrt{5}$ and $1$ (counted twice).*